# Facebook deep linking to a profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking

Trying to deep link to Facebook on iOS. I have this type of link out of a dictionary:

`"facebook_url" = "https://www.facebook.com/<string_chosen_by_user>";`

Which doesn't work, but if I have

`"facebook_url" = "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=<id_number>";`

it does work. Does anyone know of a way to get the 1st one to deep link? I'll keep digging as well.

Comment: I may be wrong, but aren't those Facebook short links (like your first example) customizable?  Any given user might be at `facebook.com/JohnDoe` or `facebook.com/JohnnyD` or `facebook.com/JohnnyLovesAnts`.  Maybe it doesn't work because you're using it with users whose URLs don't follow that pattern?

Comment: The first one the user can choose anything. It is not first.last

Comment: Apologies. You're definitely right on that. Was just using it as a placeholder. The first one can be anything you choose, but if a Facebook user doesn't set their own profile URL like the 1st one, it still gives the 2nd ID number format. The 2nd one if opened on an iPhone opens the Facebook app to their profile. 1st one opens Facebook but doesn't do anything. Will edit above.